# Update array of objects using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, nosql

Helo!
I've got this JSON structure:

```
 {
    "author" : "some author"
    "comment" : [{
          "text" : "some text",
          "date" : "some date",
       }, {
           "text" : "some text",
          "date" : "some date",
       }]
}
```

And I need for example to check all comments date. I wrote this code:

```
    UpdateOperations<Blog> ops;
    Query<Blog> updateQuery = ds.createQuery(Blog.class).disableValidation().filter("comment.$.date", "some date").enableValidation();

    ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Blog.class).disableValidation().set("comment.$.text", "new text").enableValidation();
ds.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

But it doesn't work. Could you tell me how to deal with array of objects in morphia?

Answer (score 1):

The filter shouldn't have the `$` operator you can just use dot notation.  try:

```
UpdateOperations<Blog> ops;
Query<Blog> updateQuery = ds.createQuery(Blog.class).field("comment.date").equal("some date");
ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Blog.class).disableValidation().set("comment.$.text", "new text").enableValidation();
```

Comment: mongo can work with arrays almost as if they were a single object - it's a pretty nice feature actually.

Comment: It doesn't work. It still returns null, but I know there is such record.